# weird class cast exception

Tags: java, jpa, types, classcastexception

I can't understand why i've got ClassCastException at the last row of code
I thought if i had OrgStructure list parametrised - there will be no problem

```
List<MqtAsutrOrgst2> OrgStructure = null;
    Query query = null;
    ...
            ...

    OrgStructure = query.getResultList();       
    for (Object o : OrgStructure) {

        MqtAsutrOrgst2 orgStructureItem = (MqtAsutrOrgst2) o;

    }
```

p.s. MqtAsutrOrgst2 is just an @Entity

Comment: How is `MqtAsutrOrgst2` related to `OrgStructureItemType` ?

Comment: You haven't even shown us the *declaration* for `OrgStructure`, let alone what the query's doing. The fact that `orgstructItems` is parameterized doesn't change the contents of `OrgStructure` at all...

Comment: Does `for (MqtAsutrOrgst2 o : OrgStructure)` do the same thing?

Comment: Leeward, in case of [for (MqtAsutrOrgst2 o : OrgStructure)] i've got same Exception, but at this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so finally problem was caused by missing one of the fields in materialised query table which was mapped on MqtAsutrOrgst2 class
thanx all

Answer (score 2):

> I can't understand why i've got ClassCastException at the last row of code

What I understand is `MqtAsutrOrgst2` is subclass or implementation type of `OrgStructureItemType` class . The `List orgstructItems` is defined to keep anything that is a sub type of `OrgStructureItemType` which includes `MqtAsutrOrgst2` and probably some other sub classes as well which cannot be casted between one another.

```
MqtAsutrOrgst2 orgStructureItem = (MqtAsutrOrgst2) o;
```

You are forcing the compiler to believe that at runtime the object `o` will be an object of `MqtAsutrOrgst2` , but actually it is an object of some other sub class of `OrgStructureItemType` which cannot be cast to `MqtAsutrOrgst2`.

There are better ways to do this , but you can do a temporary fix :

```
if(o instanceof MqtAsutrOrgst2)     
  MqtAsutrOrgst2 orgStructureItem = (MqtAsutrOrgst2) o;
```

The below code will be a quick fail :

```
for (MqtAsutrOrgst2 o : OrgStructure) { ... }
```

Comment: Seems that MqtAsutrOrgst2 is a subclass of OrgStructure, not OrgStructureItemType.

Comment: @artplastika may be but it seems unclear what that `query.getResultList()` returns :(

Comment: OrgStructure.getClass(): class org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingResultList and forget about OrgStructureItemType

Comment: o instanceof MqtAsutrOrgst2 = false

Comment: @Sergey Hence you get that Exception !

Comment: @The New Idiot, so any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just try to log the type of the object and everything should be clear

Comment: im trying to log and even if i do `OrgStructure = (List<MqtAsutrOrgst2>) query.getResultList();`  i've got  `OrgStructure.getClass(): class org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingResultList`  wtf?

Comment: try to log class of o Object inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that MqtAsutrOrgst2 is a subclass of OrgStructure. Seems you get list of OrgStructure using JPA. We need more information on Query object that you use. But most likely you use Query that constructs exactly objects of superclass OrgStructure.

Comment: query.getResultList() returns org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingResultList

Comment: right! Query constructs exactly objects of superclass OrgStructure but why it turns into DelegatingResultList. And what can i do with that? any ideas?

Comment: > OrgStructure but why it turns into DelegatingResultList - That's ok, because you assign it from getResultList(). Please show the code where you create Query object and declaration of class MqtAsutrOrgst2 with all annotations applied to that class.